# Different Formulae for the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Whiles trying to derive the Fourier transform I cam across a part in my text book about the other forms of the transform. [image: Fouire Transforms]

My question is what role does this play, as it what the applications of the different transformations. Or is it the fact certain transformations work better or certain functions?

Comment: What you have posted are three equivalent versions of the Fourier transform---they are all the same transform.  They differ only in where you decide to hide the constant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions

Comment: Ah I kept thinking that but, what was troubling me is why, why do we not just stick to one version?

Comment: @JasonTaylor Stick with one version, great. Which one? It's too late, different authors use different versions.